# jquery dialog.load, retrieve url inside dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog, jquery-load

I have a dialog. the content is another page.

```
var myUrl = 'DummyUrl.aspx?...';
$(".dialog").load(myUrl).dialog('open');
```

inside the dialog, I want, in javascript, get the url ('DummyUrl.aspx?...').
But when I use things like document.URL or top.location, it return the url of the page containing the dialog.

Comment: Why not just use the `myUrl` value you used in the `load`?

Comment: usually, the content of the dialog dont know this value. Only the container does.